# Storm Multi-threading Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-storm, esper

We have a distributed topology set up on 3 nodes that has 2 workers, it looks as follows:

```
JMSDataSpout (1,1)
ParseBolt (4,4)
EsperBolt (2,2)
JMSBolt (2,2)
```

For each component above: (parallelism hint, number of tasks)

The issue we are seeing is that when we run our topology the second EsperBolt thread never gets assigned any work.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Comment: so , you never reach the last bolt ? are you sure that your emit is right on the first bolt ?